# MiniCssExtractPlugin doesn't minify css code with webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, minify

Webpack version: 4.35.3

All compilation is successful.
My code after compilation in bundle.css is not minify.
I try to use minimize: true in text-webpack-plugin, but it not working.

For compile I use command in command line: webpack in my working directory

What am I doing wrong?
Why does MiniCssExtractPlugin not work, maybe because of resolve-url-loader?

My wepback config:

````
const AssetsWebpackPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin')
const FileManagerPlugin = require('filemanager-webpack-plugin')
const { PATH } = require('../constants')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    path: PATH.publicFolder,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'static/react/js/[name].[contenthash].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/react/js/[name].[contenthash].js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'static/react/js/[name].[contenthash].js.map',
    jsonpFunction: 'reactJsonpFunction',
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
  watch: false,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
    }),
    new AssetsWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'static/react/assets.json',
      path: PATH.publicFolder,
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'static/react/css/common.css',
    }),
    new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({
      logo: PATH.favicon,
      prefix: 'static/react/icons/',
      emitStats: false,
      statsFilename: 'iconstats.json',
      background: '#fff',
      persistentCache: true,
      inject: true,
      icons: {
        android: true,
        appleIcon: true,
        appleStartup: true,
        coast: false,
        favicons: true,
        firefox: true,
        opengraph: false,
        twitter: false,
        yandex: false,
        windows: false,
      },
    }),
    new FileManagerPlugin({
      onStart: {
        delete: ['../jrp-web-app/static/react/'],
      },
      onEnd: {
        mkdir: ['../jrp-web-app/static/react/'],
        copy: [
          {
            source: 'public/static/react',
            destination: '../jrp-web-app/static/react',
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'static/react/images/[name]-[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: false,
            },
          },
          'resolve-url-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: false,
              config: {
                path: PATH.postcssConfig,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Did you use bundle.css in any of your js files? If not, mini-css-extract-plugin will just ignore it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).